# Print the path of the max sum and the sum in array

Tags: c++, matrix

Im doing task, where I have to find maximum sum path in a Matrix and print the path and the sum. I made that part with finding the sum, but i cant print the path. Can you help me? Here is what I do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> 
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
#define N 100 

int n, m;
int a[N][N];

vector<vector<int> > dp(N, vector<int>(N)),
visited(N, vector<int>(N));

int currentSum = 0;

int totalSum = 0;

void inputMatrix()
{
    n = 3;
    m = 3;
    a[0][0] = 500;
    a[0][1] = 100;
    a[0][2] = 230;
    a[1][0] = 1000;
    a[1][1] = 100;
    a[1][2] = 100;
    a[2][0] = 200;
    a[2][1] = 1000;
    a[2][2] = 200;
}

int maximumSumPath(int i, int j)
{
    if (i == n - 1 && j == m - 1)
        return a[i][j];

    if (visited[i][j])
        return dp[i][j];

    // Marking (i, j) is visited 
    visited[i][j] = 1;

    int& totalSum = dp[i][j];

    if (i < n - 1 && j < m - 1) 
    {
        int current_sum = max(maximumSumPath(i, j + 1), maximumSumPath(i + 1, j));
        totalSum = a[i][j] + current_sum;
    }   
    else if (i == n - 1)
    {
        totalSum = a[i][j] + maximumSumPath(i, j + 1);  
    }
    else
    {
        totalSum = a[i][j] + maximumSumPath(i + 1, j);
    }
    return totalSum;

}

int main()
{
    inputMatrix();   
    int maximumSum = maximumSumPath(0, 0);
    cout << maximumSum << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

What would be the best way to print the path with the maximum sum?

Thank in advance!

Comment: Use the information in your `dp` array. You start at (0, 0), and you use the values in the array to figure out which step you should take. Repeat until you're at the end.

Comment: Your exact question has been answered on GeeksforGeeks: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-path-sum-matrix/ and check here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-sum-path-in-a-matrix/?ref=rp

Comment: @BessieTheCow i did not understand

Comment: First compute the maximum sum. Then you start at (0, 0), and you compare `dp[0][1]` with `dp[1][0]`. Say `dp[0][1]` is greater. Then you change your position to (0, 1), and you compare `dp[0][2]` to `dp[1][1]` and repeat until you get to the bottom right corner.

Comment: But its the same above.